# C# Entity Framework and stored procedures

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I made my database with its stored procedures then attached it with my project Entity Framework database-first.

This function to insert a company info and return its id back and insert it to another table in relation with company table

```
public string InsertCompany(company company, out int index)
{
        try
        {
            using (vendors_managerEntities db = new vendors_managerEntities())
            {
                db.companies.Add(company);
                db.SaveChanges();
                index = company.id_company;
                return $"{company.name_company} Is Saved";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            index = 0;
            return ex.Message;
        }
}
```

But when I tried to my stored procedure which has been created in database, I couldn't return any value the id always be 0

```
public string InsertCompany(company company, out int index)
{
        try
        {
            using (vendors_managerEntities db = new vendors_managerEntities())
            {
                db.SP_insert_companies(company.name_company, company.website_company, company.adress_company, company.county_company, company.decription_company);
                index = company.id_company;
                return $"{company.name_company} Is Saved";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            index = 0;
            return ex.Message;
        }
}
```

I read that I can make it in SQL but I'm looking for a solution in C#, so I opened the stored procedure definition in C# and found the following code and was thinking if can I change its return value because it's not return the id value

```
public virtual int SP_insert_companies(string name, string website, string address, string country, string description)
{
        var nameParameter = name != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("name", name) :
            new ObjectParameter("name", typeof(string));

        var websiteParameter = website != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("website", website) :
            new ObjectParameter("website", typeof(string));

        var addressParameter = address != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("address", address) :
            new ObjectParameter("address", typeof(string));

        var countryParameter = country != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("country", country) :
            new ObjectParameter("country", typeof(string));

        var descriptionParameter = description != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("description", description) :
            new ObjectParameter("description", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SP_insert_companies", nameParameter, websiteParameter, addressParameter, countryParameter, descriptionParameter);
}
```

Please tell me if there's a solution in C# or should I go back to old code without stored procedure in that case?

Comment: Just glancing over this the first thing I noticed is that you're returning ex.Message and your last few lines of code have the index set to 0.. Is that a typo?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You call a stored procedure with some string values. How should that company.id_company be updated? I do not think EF can see the relation between the two

Comment: its bad practice to return the exception as a string...instead throw the exception and use structured error handling

Comment: @HansKeﬆing id_company should created auto because it's IDENTITY(1,1) in database

Comment: @Ctznkane525 thanks bro of course i will do but for now i focus on an issue

Comment: @marc_s thanks for making my question looks better ^^

Comment: @AbdelrhmanElsaid Yes, in the *database* the id is automatically set. But why would some object in your code suddenly also get that value? You should maybe return that autogenerated ID from your stored procedure. See the answer by JuanR

Comment: `db.companies.Add(company);
db.SaveChanges(); 
index = company.id_company;`
with this way i can back with id of just inserted company so i would back to it in this case @HansKeﬆing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a stored procedure to insert the `company` entity which I suspect does not cause the object to be refreshed by the context:

```
db.SP_insert_companies(company.name_company, company.website_company, company.adress_company, company.county_company, company.decription_company);
```

You then try to get the id from the object which is `0` because it hasn't been refreshed:

```
index = company.id_company;
```

If you insist on using a stored procedure, what I would suggest is that you have the SP return the id of the company, then grab it from the call and use that as the value of `index`:

```
index = db.SP_insert_companies(company.name_company, company.website_company, company.adress_company, company.county_company, company.decription_company);
```

Once you modify the SP, make sure to update the definition in your code so it knows to make a function that returns a value.

If you prefer to have it in the object itself, then make sure to update it manually, although I don't recommend this as the object is not in true sync with the database:

```
index = db.SP_insert_companies(company.name_company, company.website_company, company.adress_company, company.county_company, company.decription_company);
company.id_company = index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying it's automatically going to the "Catch" and then the index is already set to 0. So chances are your code elsewhere, not listed is messing up. I suspect wherever your code for saving the company information isn't saving properly. Try manually inputting a company into the DB and then check it with your program. If it returns that it's "Saved" then you know your problem isn't within this method and is a result of your saving method.

Comment: my database works and as i said above i can catch id in index using db.companies.add(company); but with store producer i can't catch the id